# Activation function derivative in backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I'm implementing NN compression methods described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03009),
where they show backpropagation equations for calculating weight updates (page 3):

[image]

Then there's a statement I'm struggling to understand:

> The expression h'(Wx + b) contains downflowing gradients, which are
>   largely determined by the cost function and network parameters.

If I understand correctly, this expression is just a derivative of the activation function at the point Wx+b, where x is a vector of the lower layer activations, and therefore it has nothing to do with downflowing gradients.

The statement is important in the context of what they're trying to do (reduce the precision of computation), so I'd like to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the authors?

Comment: Not yet, first I'd like to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: Well, derivative matrix *is* the gradient. They denote the error signal by $delta$, which is what you had in mind, I guess. But it looks odd, I agree. I think the statement makes sense, if you change "cost function" to "activation function", doesn't it?

Comment: It seems like they really do mean downflowing gradients because they claim later in the paper that's why it's hard to bound the output of that expression.